# In Mac, with Xee, from command line, how to open image in its original size?

Tags: macos

In Mac, with [Xee](http://wakaba.c3.cx/s/apps/xee), from command line, how to open image in its original size?

The reason I need this is to script the process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this function to your `~/.bash_profile`. Save the file, then reload your shell.

```
function xee() {
open -a "Xee" "$1"
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "0" using command down'
}
```

Then call it with:

```
xee ~/path/to/image.jpg
```

Feel free to remix this into a proper AppleScript `.scpt` file using Automator or similar. Depending on the speed of Xee launching, you might want to add a delay between opening Xee and the UI automation (from `osascript)`.

Comment: It does NOT open the image file with its original size.

Comment: What happens instead? It works for me. You do mean the *Actual Size* option from *View*?

Comment: If the image is larger then the screen size, your script opens the image with a zoom level such that it fills the height.  This was the main problem I wanted to solve: automatically opening the image in original size.

Comment: If Xee is incapable of doing that, what *lightweight* image viewer can do it on Mac OS X?  I potentially need to open/close images several hundred times a day.  So I really need the app to be a light weight one, i.e. starts/closes fast.

Comment: Also, I wonder what does `osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "0" using command down'` do?

Comment: It presses the *Actual Size* option from the *View* menu in Xee. It renders the image in its original size. I still don't understand you — what do you need instead?